# spotfire crosstable color by another column

Tags: spotfire, crosstable

I have one question about spotfire cross table using another column

I want to aggregate using column 'VALUE' but color by columns 'FLAG'.

I heard that this function was embedded in spotfire after version 11.2
https://community.tibco.com/s/article/What-s-New-in-TIBCO-Spotfire-11-2#colorcrosstablecellsbyothercolumns

Is there any idea implementing this problem?

Thanks!

table_A

[image]

table_B
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the properties for the cross table and go to the color tab.
Check the 'Color the grouping using another expression'.
Specify the expression to color by in the field below the checkbox, see the attached image.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Fredrik, but this feature is available over spotfire version 11.2.
And my version is under 11.2.. So I need another solution. Anyway, thank you for answer